# Open documents in specified spaces

Tags: macos, applescript, high-sierra, preview, spaces

Often I need to work with three documents for one school subject, which remains the case for the school year. I have a shortcut that will open all three document in the current space (just simple `open` command), but I wonder if it is possible to specify the space in which a document is opened. Is that possible (probably through applescript)?

Comment: completely untested, but you could have a look at this - https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=23453

Comment: @Tetsujin I have came across this when I'm researching for this question, but I have close to zero knowledge of applescript so I would have to find some time to research it.